# How to handle RGB images in Keras

Tags: image, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to train a simple neural net with manually-curated dataset of images and associated labels.

I've created a numpy to create the labels called facey_label.

I've used matplotlib's imread function to turn each of 811 images into an array of shape (255, 255, 3) and then planned to use the np.array function to create a tensor img_array of shape (811, 255, 255, 3)

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(811, 255, 255, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', 
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(img_array, facey_label, epochs=5)
```

However, I receive the error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_1_input to have 5 dimensions, but got array with shape (811, 250, 250, 3)
```

What have I got wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not include the batch size in input_shape. Try with this model instead:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(255, 255, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
```

Comment: A "placeholder" for the batch size can be put explicitly with `keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(None, 255, 255, 3))`.

Comment: It worked, but ran out of memory. Time to tweak images. Thank you both, though.